# Questions on ASP.NET Core model validation (when to use nullable and [Required])

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Say in my ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app I have the following model:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public DateTime WhenAdded { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

When a user creates a car, I want to ensure on the client and on the server that **every** property has a value. Libraries for jQuery unobtrusive validation:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I've spent lots of time searching the docs and SO on what values pass the jQuery unobtrusive validation and server-side validation, but I still don't know for sure. It becomes very confusing with nullable types (on which Visual Studio insists) and `[Required]` attribute.

Regarding my Car model, I guess if the `Name` field is empty it won't pass neither client nor server validation, but `Price` field would because it evaluates to 0? Also the Create form will be displayed with `Price` set to 0 by default (which is not the desired behavior)? If so, I should make `Price` and `WhenAdded` properties nullable and `[Required]`, and just ignore the numerous proposed null-checks.

In the Create form for a car I want to have a `<select>` element with the default `<option value="">Choose category...</option>` which should not pass client/server-side validation when selected. Non-nullable `Category` and `CategoryId` properties seem to work for this?

Can you tell me if I'm wrong somewhere, and what should my Car model really look like? (I know I should actually use a CarViewModel, this is just for educational purposes)

Comment: in Data Annotation numbers are required field by default

Comment: Can you give me full HTML code input form for a Car?

Comment: There's a lot more attributes than `Required`, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations). You likely want [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute) for numbers and [StringLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute) for your Name. You can also do more advanced validation by implementing [IValidatableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check this part of [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-the-required-attribute):

> The validation system treats non-nullable parameters or bound
> properties as if they had a [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
> attribute.

.....

> On the server, a required value is considered missing if the property
> is null. A non-nullable field is always valid, and the [Required]
> attribute's error message is never displayed.
>
> However, model binding for a non-nullable property may fail, resulting
> in an error message such as The value '' is invalid. To specify a
> custom error message for server-side validation of non-nullable types,
> you have the following options:
>
> Make the field nullable (for example, decimal? instead of decimal).
> Nullable value types are treated like standard nullable types.
>
> Specify the default error message to be used by model binding, as
> shown in the following example:

```
.AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.MaxModelValidationErrors = 50;
        options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(
            _ => "The field is required.");
    });
```

I Suggest you try with

```
[Required]
public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
```

to avoid model binding error

If you don't want user select the default option,for client validation,you need a selectlist item like below:

```
selist.Insert(0,new SelectListItem() { Text = "Select" ,Disabled=true,Selected=true});
```

[image]